# Staying on same page after updating search data in flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I need to stay on the search result after updating row. Currently, I am using `update.html` to post data to `@update` after that render `update.html` and call `update` modal of bootstrap to get data from particular row. After that call `update_two` to update row in mysql using SqlAlchemy. Then trying to stay at the search result.

app.py

```
@app.route('/update', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update():
    # all_data = BankData.query.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        start_date = request.form.get('start_date')
        end_date = request.form.get('end_date')

        searched_data = db.session.query(BankData).filter(
            BankData.process_date.between(start_date, end_date))

    # db.session.add(searched_data)
    # db.session.commit()

    return render_template('update.html', start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date, searched_data=searched_data)


@app.route('/update_two', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update_two():

    # searched_data = session.get('searched_data')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_data = BankData.query.get(request.form.get('true_id'))

        new_data.process_date = request.form['date']
        new_data.description = request.form['description']
        new_data.debit = request.form['debit']
        new_data.category = request.form['category']
        db.session.commit()

    return redirect(request.url)
```

update.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% include 'header.html' %}
{%block title%} Home {%endblock%}

{%block body%}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col md-12">
            <div class="jumbotron p-3">
                <h2>Bank Transaction date from <b
                        style="margin: 15px; background-color: dimgrey;">{{start_date}}</b>-To-<b
                        style="margin: 15px; background-color: dimgrey;">{{end_date}}</b></h2>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-hover table-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Debit</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <!-- <th>Category</th> -->
                </tr>

                {% for data in searched_data %}
                <tr>
                    <!-- <td>{{data.id}}</td> -->
                    <td>{{data.process_date}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.description}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.debit}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.category}}</td>

                    <td>
                        <a href="/update/{{data.id}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-toggle="modal"
                            data-target="#modaledit{{data.id}}">Edit</a>
                        <!-- <a href="/delete/{{data.id}}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"
                            onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure To Delete ?')">Delete</a> -->
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <!-- Modal Edit Employee-->
                <div id="modaledit{{data.id}}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Update Information</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form action="{{url_for('update_two')}}" method="POST">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Date</label>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="true_id" value="{{data.id}}">

                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date"
                                            value="{{data.process_date}}">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Description</label>

                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description"
                                            value="{{data.description}}">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Debit:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="debit" value="{{data.debit}}">

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Category:</label>

                                        <select id="category" name="category">
                                            <option selected value="None">{{data.category}}</option>
                                            <option value="BankFees">Bank Fees</option>
                                            <option value="StaffExpences">Staff Expence</option>
                                            <option value="Refund">Refund</option>
                                            <option value="Telephone">Telephone</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Update</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

{%endblock%}
```

Comment: I for got to copy @app, however that's not the issue

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct:

With `/update` endpoint you render search results from the database, and then with `/update_two` endpoint, you update the database with new data or so...

And then you would like that after `/update_two` finishes it's job to see previous or new search results (that was done with `/update` endpoint), so you could change what you return in `/update_two`, so it would redirect to 1st endpoint `/update` like this:

```py
from flask import url_for


@app.route('/update_two', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update_two():
    # searched_data = session.get('searched_data')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_data = BankData.query.get(request.form.get('true_id'))

        new_data.process_date = request.form['date']
        new_data.description = request.form['description']
        new_data.debit = request.form['debit']        
        new_data.category = request.form['category']
        db.session.commit()

    return redirect(url_for('update'))
```